# Traverse to the deepest using Java

Tags: java, loops

I have a data structure like below:

```
Task(id,name,subTasks[Task])
```

But the problem is the subTasks can contain Tasks which have another subTasks. This can run to very deep like this:

```
Task1 Contains SubTask1
```

SubTask1 contains it's sub tasks

and you can understand this can be run to very deep.

I can retrieve these data from a database  tables. But how can I store this in a data structure in java. Using for loops without knowing the deep is useless and not a elegant way. What would be the best data structure and data traversal way?

Comment: If you want persistent storage (ie, not just in memory) then consider a graph database like neo4j, which includes its own traversal API

Comment: What DBMS do you use?

Answer (score 21):

Use Guava TreeTraverser:

```
Task root = ...

/*
 * For example, you have the following tree:
 *
 *          h
 *        / | \
 *       /  e  \
 *      d       g
 *     /|\      |
 *    / | \     f
 *   a  b  c        
 */

TreeTraverser<Task> traverser = new TreeTraverser<Task>() {
    @Override
    public Iterable<Task> children(Task root) {
        return root.subTasks;
    }
};
```

Then you can iterate over the tree with `for` loop in several ways:

```
// Iterate in breadth-first order (hdegabcf)
for (Task task : traverser.breadthFirstTraversal(root)) { ... }
```

or

```
// Iterate in preorder (hdabcegf)
for (Task task : traverser.preOrderTraversal(root)) { ... }
```

or

```
// Iterate in postorder (abcdefgh)
for (Task task : traverser.postOrderTraversal(root)) { ... }
```

Comment: how to convert of Map <Parent, Child> to Guava TreeTraverser

Comment: @piyushGoyal I think you probably want Multimap instead of Map. In that case it is `TreeTraverser.using(multimap::get)`

Answer (score 3):

Data structure: the implicit tree formed by object references.

Traversal: recursion or queues.

However, you will have to consider each use case individually. Some will call for depth-first traversal, some for breadth-first traversal. Consider using some graph library to build the trees in the first place if you need a lot of graph operations.

Comment: Recursive way may not work the all time if we have more depth.

Comment: If your tasks are nested deeper than your available stack space allows, that's a very scary task architecture.

Comment: Maybe he wants to omit a lot of database queries and reduce database traffic. In this case everything depends on the DBMS type. If it is Oracle he can use CONNECT BY operator. Or create a closure table.