# SDK method for Tree traversal

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, tree

```
class TreeNode {
    private int val;
    TreeNode left;
    TreeNode right;

    TreeNode(int x) {
        val = x;
    }
}
```

Is there any sdk method that makes any type of [traverse](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/63921/print-all-nodes-from-root-to-leaves) through all nodes of my simple tree-like data structure? I believe, it could  be useful for unit tests.

Comment: what do you mean "..sdk method"?

Comment: I mean java.util.Collections; java.util.Arrays ; etc

Comment: there is a `TreeMap` within `java.util`, but I am not sure if that's what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Core java dose not have such methods but you can use Guava library [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18591636/traverse-to-the-deepest-using-java)
this library supports various tree traverse forms (in-order, pre-order ...)